# PC starts a booting process then shuts down and repeats (after installing new parts)

Tags: boot, memory, ssd, windows-11, bluetooth

so I ran into a problem today.
After I installed everything into my new case and some new parts. When I went to change my ram speeds and save it to 3000MHz my PC enters a boot attempt then shuts down after a few attempts it boots correctly and for now it's stable but it locks the ram speed to 2133MHz. The new parts are the 2 Corsiar RAM sticks, a new SATA SSD 1 TB, a Noctua fan and a wifi/Bluetooth extension card.

build:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600x
- Ram: 2sticks Kingston HyperX fury 8gb ddr4/ 2sticks corsair Vengence RGB Pro sl 3200Mhz 8gb
- PSU: 650W bronze
- Graphics Card: Nvidia RTX 3060ti

theoretically, I shouldn't be having this issue because I installed 2 new RAM sticks an SSD and a fan

Comment: If you return everything to the original configuration except the memory does the system boot?

Comment: it always boots but it starts the repeating process and then locks the memory back to the base of 2133

Comment: In the case, it sounds like the memory, is not compatible with the system.  The system rebooting, in my experience, actually a sign of performing memory training.  However, you have not provided enough information, to identify your original HyperX memory

Comment: "Some new parts..." It might help if you were *specific* about what parts were removed, and what replacements were made.

Comment: Update it was the corsair ram sticks causing the issue for some reason I tested every stick individually and only the corsair began that process so I'm gonna call for a refund/switch tmr morning

Comment: I have a couple of AMD motherboards that are particularly sensitive to the RAM - what motherboard do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple reboot is a failure to post. On most systems multiple failures to post at about 3 times will reset, because it believes a possible misconfig in the bios is causing he error, exempli gratia booting after several successive.

System locks are common in overclocking, are all the components RATED for what you are setting them at? If not this is the system correcting you.

For MB that support multiple  CPU/Ram speeds etc in the modern world this is almost always a detection not a setting. I have not seen a computer you had to manually set speeds in years.